# Mac OS X & Docker 1.9.1 Insecure registry location

Tags: macos, configuration, docker, docker-machine

I am trying to configure my Docker instance to allow insecure registries on my Mac.  However, in the new installation for Docker, I can't find which config file to place the

> --insecure-registry host:port

I see in some places to put it in the /etc/default/docker file, yet the folder default doesn't exist.  I've even tried reating a docker file in the /etc/defaults dir to no avail.

I could really use some insight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `docker-machine` with the `--engine-insecure-registry` to accomplish this on Mac. If you initially created your machine with name `dev` you will need to stop and remove it first:

```
docker-machine stop dev
docker-machine rm dev
```

Then, assuming your registry was at `registry.mydomain.internal:8443` you would create the new machine using:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-insecure-registry registry.mydomain.internal:8443 dev
```